In Spring Boot, how can I initialize database before context creation?
I want to initialize my database before Spring context is created. Then I want to initialize my components based on the content in the database.
How do I do this?
e.g. my component:
@Component
class MyService(val personRepository: PersonRepository) {
    var persons = personRepository.findAll()
    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        persons = personRepository.findAll()
        println("Counted initial people: " + persons.count())
    }

Repository:
@Repository
interface PersonRepository : CrudRepository<Person, Long>

Person:
@Entity
@Table(schema = "test", name = "test_table")
class Person {
    @Id
    lateinit var id: String

    var name: String? = null
}

Test like this:
@SpringBootTest
@Sql(scripts = ["/data.sql"])
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(type = AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.DatabaseType.POSTGRES)
@TestPropertySource(locations = ["classpath:application-testing.properties"])
class ApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var myService: MyService

    @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
        println("Counted persons in test: " + myService.personRepository.findAll().count())
    }

This typically results in output:
Counted initial persons: 0
Counted persons in test: 4

so the data is not initialized in MyService.init() but available later during test execution.
I tried various combinations, but always it executes data creation scripts only after context initialization.
In particular, I tried:

@Sql annotation as above, including specifying executionPhase parameter
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:data.sql in application properties
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true and having the file data.sql with data

Any suggestions of how to initialize the db before Spring context is initialized?
